# Nonsingular matrix $M\in \mathbb{C}^{n,n}$ . Conclusions.

Tags: linear-algebra

Matrix $M\in \mathbb{C}^{n,n}$ is nonsingular. Then:
a. vectors $Ae_1, Ae_2, \ldots, Ae_n$ is base of $\mathbb{C}^n$
b. matrixes $e_1^TA, \ldots, e_n^TA$ is base of $\mathbb{C}^{1,n}$.
c. endomorphism $f:\mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$  such that $f(x)=Ax$ is isomorphism.

a.  It is true. Let's note that columns are linearly independent. Moreover we have exactly $n$ columns so columns are base of $\mathbb{C}^n$. We can equivalently multiply $A\cdot I_n = A$.
b.  It is also true, the only difference between a. and b. is orientation of vector - it doesn't matter.
c. According to a. it is epimorphism. When it comes to monomorphism: $f$ is monomorphism if only and only $\ker f = \{0\}$.
$Ax = 0\Leftrightarrow x = A^{-1}0\Leftrightarrow x = 0$.  So $f$ is iso
morphism.

Can you check my solutions ?

Comment: It looks as if $M=A$ ? Answer depends a bit upon what you what knowledge (definitions  + theorems) you  may use.

Comment: Yes, $M=A$. I may use all what I used

Comment: ok, but what is your definition of $A=M$ being nonsingular? (e.g. columns linearly indep? then (b) is not that trivial)

Comment: Yes, but also non-zero determinant, rank=n, reversibility. What about corectness ? After all, (b) and (a) are the same task - only thing is orientation of vectors

Comment: Ok, if you may use determinants, equivalence with $\det=0$ and know that $\det A=\det A^T$ then the two first amount to the same (otherwise non-trivial). But I think you should add something about $\det$ to your solution. Your solution for monomorphism is not good. It presumes already that $A$ has an inverse. You may instead use a dimensional argument (or you may use (b)). If not clear, I can develop.

Comment: I may use the fact that nonsingular is reversible, so $A^{-1}$ exists

Comment: Ok, then that part is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that a. and b. are correct. In fact, $A$ is nonsingular (=regular) if and only if it sends any base of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ to a base of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$.

Imho c. is right as well, perhaps more geometrical solution comes to my mind, if you are familiar with the [SVD decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition). Then you can observe that since $A$ is nonsingular, all singular values of $A$ are positive and hence acting of $A$ in fact noly rotates, stretches and then again rotates the space $\mathbb{C}^n$. From geometrical point of view this means that $A$ essentially only "relabels" the points of $\mathbb{C}^n$, which is equivalent to the isomorphism property. This may also pop some geometrical insight into a. and b. tasks.